# php abstract class extending another abstract class

Tags: php

Is it possible in PHP, that an abstract class inherits from an abstract class?

For example,

```
abstract class Generic {
    abstract public function a();
    abstract public function b();
}

abstract class MoreConcrete extends Generic {
    public function a() { do_stuff(); }
    abstract public function b(); // I want this not to be implemented here...
}

class VeryConcrete extends MoreConcrete {
    public function b() { do_stuff(); }

}
```

( [abstract class extends abstract class in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789328/abstract-class-extends-abstract-class-in-php) does not give an answer)

Comment: Have you actually run the code before asking here?

Comment: @Jakub i think it is possible upto my knowledge

Comment: Yes. It did not work. Because... of `abstract public function b();` in the second class. Without it it goes. Question answered

Comment: Why the hell would you not use interfaces and traits

Comment: @ied3vil Traits were not yet available in PHP when the question was posted.

Comment: Don't forget, abstract functions override is allowed from PHP 7.2 only  !

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

If a subclass does not implements all abstract methods of the abstract superclass, it must be abstract too.

Comment: without `abstract public function b();` in the second class it works... answered, thanks

Comment: Note that the order of the definitions matters.  If you put the class VeryConcrete first, you will get 'Fatal error: Class 'MoreConcrete' not found' error.  Be careful not to put the abstract cart before the horse.

Answer (score 6):

It will work, even if you leave the abstract function b(); in class MoreConcrete.

But in this specific example I would transform class "Generic" into an Interface, as it has no more implementation beside the method definitions.

```
interface Generic {
    public function a(); 
    public function b();
}

abstract class MoreConcrete implements Generic {
    public function a() { do_stuff(); }
    // can be left out, as the class is defined abstract
    // abstract public function b();
}

class VeryConcrete extends MoreConcrete {
    // this class has to implement the method b() as it is not abstract.
    public function b() { do_stuff(); }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible however your code would not work if you called `$VeryConcreteObject->b()`

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php#78388) is more detailed explanation.